# Javascript - Button Fails to load submit function

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a very simple login system but the submit button doesn't seem to load the php page. I have tried loading function etc using the submit and they work fine. I have copied and pasted the function name to ensure it is correct. I have know idea why it doesn't seem to work, Any response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="MainDiv">
    <div id="Header">
      <div id="Logo">
        <img src="../Scotia Sea Life Logo.png" width="150px" height="110px" 
             alt="Company Logo"/>
      </div>
      <div id="NavBar">
        <ul>
          <a href="../Homepage.html" style="text-decoration:none;">Home</a>
          <a href="../Tours/Tours.html">Tours</a>
          <a href="AdditionPageMain.php">About</a>
          <a href="SubtractionPageMain.php">Donate</a>
          <a href="Devisionmain.php">Account</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="Title">Register</div>
      <div id="Content">
        <div id="RegisterDetails">
          <form id="RegisterForm" name="RegisterForm" method="POST" 
                action="RegisterInsert.php">
            <table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="15%">Email Address:</td>
                <td width="85%">
                  <input type="text" name="txt_Email" id="txt_Email" 
                         onblur="Register()"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="15%">Username:</td>
                <td width="85%">
                  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="user_name" 
                         id="user_name" class="user_name" onblur="Register()" />
                  <span class="check" id="spanCheck"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="15%">Password:</td>
                <td width="85%">
                  <input type="password" name="txt_Password" id="txt_Password"
                         onblur="Register()"/>
                  Min Password Length 6 char
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="submit" name="btn_Register" id="btn_Register" 
                         value="Register" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Footer">
        <div id="FooterLinks"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- I have placed js at bottom in order to make page load faster -->
  <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="UsernameValidation.php"></script>
  <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
  <script src="EmailValidation.php"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console ? The scripts you have added Usernamevalidation.php and EmailValidation.php in script are not JavaScript files. Is the function (Register() that you have used is a valid JavaScript function ?

Comment: No, That is why i am confused.

Comment: The Register() function is only used to make the button.disabled = true/false. The other two php file have no relation to the RegisterInsert.php file, they are simply used for user input validation using ajax. The RegisterInsert.php just takes the values of the 3 textboxes and inserts it into the db.